# Is there a c# opensource OCR that can pull info off a personal check?

Tags: c#, ocr

I am scanning several checks at once and I am looking to get the following information by passing the check image through an OCR.

- Name(s)
- Address
- Check Number
- Routing Number
- Account Number
- Amount (Hand Written)

Ammount is the biggie I can get account number from the check scanner

IS ther an open source or sample of doing this in C#?

Comment: This smells like somthing very dangerous.. actually, extermely dangerous.. if you still going to do that - use at least 5 diffrent OCR's and only if all of them give the same result flag it as valid. But honestly even with that I still wouldn't trust OCR to get that input.

Comment: The UI I am building requires that you review all the data collected. This is the same way many banks make large deposits now.

Comment: Yup, I figured that the UI will require the user to manually review all data collected - and this is exacly why I think it is dangerous. :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but i need to do the same thing. How did you finally managed to do it?

Comment: @JameyMcElveen Did you manage to create your check OCR app?  I am trying to do the same thing with Tesseract and would love to know how to do things like using Tesseract to identify the account/routing numbers based on the symbols next to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called Tesseract which I used to get info from a passport (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

I just shelled it out to do the execution and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Hi Neil, if possible can you share the training data your are using for reading passports?

Comment: Apologies but I didn't use training sets as the plain tesseract worked just fine.

Comment: Can you share your code ? I`m trying to make the same thing and i`m getting a lot of trouble. :D

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract is a good open-source option. I'm using as the engine in a C# program (with the C# wrapper Tessnet2). I also have a verification stage in my program, so you can see what has been recognized and confirm or fix it.